# Which data to plot to know what model suits best for the problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, plot, prediction

I'm sorry, i know that this is a very basic question but since i'm still a beginner in machine learning, determining what model suits best for my problem is still confusing to me, lately i used linear regression model (causing the `r2_score` is so low) and a user mentioned i could use certain model according to the curve of the plot of my data and when i see another coder use random forest regressor (causing the `r2_score` 30% better than the linear regression model) and i do not know how the heck he/she knows better model since he/she doesn't mention about it. I mean in most sites that i read, they shoved the data to some models that they think would suit best for the problem (example: for regression problem, the models could be using linear regression or random forest regressor) but in some sites and some people said firstly we need to plot the data so we can predict what exact one of the models that suit the best. I really don't know which part of the data should i plot? I thought using `seaborn pairplot` would give me insight of the shape of the curve but i doubt that it is the right way, what should i actually plot? only the label itself or the features itself or both? and how can i get the insight of the curve to know the possible best model after that?

Answer (score 1):

This question is too general, but I will try to give an overview of how to choose the model. First of all you should that there is no general rule to choose the family of models to use, it is more a choosen by experiminting different model and looking to which one gives better results. You should also now that in general you have multi-dimensional features, thus plotting the data will not give you a full insight of the dependance of your features with the target, however to check if you want to fit a linear model or not, you can start plotting the target vs each dimension of the input, and look if there is some kind of linear relation. However I would recommand that you to fit a linear model, and check if if this is relvant from a statistical point of view (student test, smirnov test, check the residuals...). Note that in real life applications, it is not likeley that linear regression will be the best model, unless you do a lot of featue engineering. So I would recommand you to use more advanced methods (RandomForests, XGboost...)

Comment: Yeah i read that some people just keep saying "plot your data first", i thought that this maybe the general rule because it kinds of make sense, by plotting it we can learn the curve shape and from that, we can determine what model possibly suit best (for example linear curve -> linear regression and logistic curve -> logistic regression). from the experience myself, i have already done this ( you can start plotting the target vs each dimension of the input, and look if there is some kind of linear relation) and i'm pretty sure from the plot it looks linear without scattering here and there

Comment: But then again, linear regression model somehow failed me and i found out that Random Forest Regressor works best so far. Do i always need to shove the data to some models? How on earth some models works better than the others for a certain problem (how can Random Forest Regressor works better than linear regression). Also do you have any links to let me know more about more advanced methods? (it's hard to find)

Comment: @potatostudent It is normal that randomForests works better then linear regression, linear is he most simple you can construct, it constratins that the labels are linear combinaison of the input, wich is to constraintive in general. In the same time, RandomForsts allow your model to construct non-linear relation, and thus it has more flexibility. The problem is that if you have to much flexibility you  overfit the train data, this why people use corss validation to select the best model to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using off-the-shelf packages like `sklearn`, then many simple models like SVM, RF, etc, are just one-liners, so in practice, we usually try several such models at the same time.

Comment: i'm sorry what do you mean by one-liner? by that so the more advanced models are for multiple liners then? do you have any links to let me know more about varieties of advanced models?

Comment: Yeah, one-liner means just one line of code. For advanced models, they are not only just multiple liners, but you need to design the model based on the problem. The most advanced models involve math derivations, but for most people, they just tune existing models, e.g. find a template of a certain type of neural network and tune parameters on your training data. You can search in GitHub, many tech blog also attach their code.